# Can Infinispan be implemented as cache manager for Apache Shiro?

Tags: caching, shiro, infinispan

Apache Shiro allows some implementations for CacheManager. EHCache is one of these implemenations.

I'd like to use Infinispan as Distributed Cache Manager. Until now, I'm not sure wheter it's feasible or not.

Does anybody know how to implement Infinispan as CacheManager for Apache Shiro ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone who's implemented a CacheManager based on Infinispan for Shiro, but we'd definitely welcome it! :). [Getting familiar](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart) with Infinispan would be the best way to start.

Answer (score 6):

I just uploaded Shiro Infinispan support project to GitHub (https://github.com/zbiljic/shiro-infinispan).

It's almost exact copy of EHCache implementation, but uses Infinispan instead.

I created this, and 'shiro-redis' project a year ago for some internal application, but never had the time to upload it.
We use it in production for some time now.